# Rails ordering not working from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a snippet from a controller below that is supposed to order a list of surveys by creation date from newest to oldest.

```
  # GET /surveys
  def index
    @survey_type = get_survey_type
    @surveys = @survey_type.surveys
    @surveys.order('created_at desc')
  end
```

For some reason whether I add or remove the 'desc' part the sort order does not change. I have done some

```
Survey.all.order('created_at')
```

and

```
Survey.all.order('created_at desc')
```

quick tests in the Rails console and there the ordering works as expected. So somewhere in this snippet presumably lies the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have:

```
@surveys = @surveys.order('created_at DESC')
```

or:

```
@surveys = @survey_type.surveys.order('created_at DESC')
```

You have this problem because you don't set `@surveys` to be an instance of `ActiveRecord::Relation` scoped with order.

Comment: Ah non-assignment - how amateur.

Comment: Another issue that I detected FWIW is that if you use DataTables it  resorts your data based on the first column and this will create a similar issue that can be confusing